# DB -STORED PROCEDURE-Not Inserting data into multiple tables when multiple service request coming

Tags: sql

In DB Stored procedure i am trying to insert data into multiple tables together with normal insert query. But if i am getting more service call at the same time. Data is not inserting in all the tables and skipping it and moving to the another request. Required solution at procedure level.

Required solution at procedure level

```
  INSERT INTO RepurchaseMaster_Reg (RegId, SprRegId, SalesTo, FId, BillNo, BillDate, TotQty, TotPV, Status, SesId, UqId, IpAddress, TotalDP, TotUnitPrice, CommDate, Remarks, CBPayNo, MemType, BillType, OrdType,      
  TaxType, TaxSubType, SaleType, TotGross, TotNet, TotValue, TotCGST, TotSGST, TotIGST, SplOffCode, SplOffAmt, TotalBP, TaxAmt, NetAmt, UpdatedDate, PayableAmount, TotMRP, RepType)      
    SELECT      
      @RegId,      
      @SprRegId,      
      @SalesTo,      
      @FId,      
      @BillNo,      
      @BillDate,      
      isnull(@TotQty,0),      
      @TotPV,      
      @Status,      
      @SessId,      
      @UqId,      
      @IpAddress,      
      @TotalDP,      
      @TotUnitPrice,      
      @CommDate,      
      @Remarks,      
      @CBPayNo,      
      @MemType,      
      @BillType,      
      @OrdType,      
      @TaxType,      
      @TaxSubType,      
      @SaleType,      
      @TotGross,      
      @TotNet,      
      @TotValue,      
      @TotCGST,      
      @TotSGST,      
      @TotIGST,      
      @SplOffCode,      
      @SplOffAmt,      
      0,      
      0,      
      0,      
      GETDATE(),      
      @PayableAmt,      
      @TotMRP,      
      @RepType      
      
  SET @RMid = @@identity      
      
  IF @BillType = 2      
  BEGIN      
      
    INSERT INTO ProductCredits (RegId, Sprno, InAmt, OutAmt, Dated, Descr, Remarks, TypeOfInc, billno, rmid, ExpiredDate, LockedDate)      
      SELECT      
        0 RegId,      
        @RegId Sprno,      
        @TotPV InAmt,      
        0 OutAmt,      
        GETDATE() Dated,      
        'Product Purchase thru ID : ' + @BillNo Descr,      
       'Thru Product Purchase' Remarks,      
        'Product Purchase' TypeOfInc,      
        @BillNo billno,      
        @RMid,      
        DATEADD(yyyy, 1, GETDATE()) ExpiredDate,      
        DATEADD(yyyy, 1, GETDATE()) LockedDate      
      
    UPDATE RepurchaseMaster_Reg      
    SET TotPV = 0      
    WHERE rmid = @RMid      
  END      
      
INSERT INTO RepurchaseItems_Reg (rmid, pid, qty, MRP, DP, UnitPrice, GrossValue, DisCount, NetValue, PV, GST, IGSTAmt, CGST, CGSTAmt, SGST, SGSTAmt, TotValue, BP, amount, BV      
  , TaxAmt, CGSTTax, CGSTTaxAmt, SGSTTax, SGSTTaxAmt)      
    SELECT      
      @rmid,      
      ISNULL(ic.ProdItemId, t.pid) pid,      
      qty,      
      MRP,      
      DP,      
      UnitPrice,      
      GrossValue,      
      DisCount,      
      NetValue,      
      PV,     
GST,      
      IGSTAmt,      
      CGST,      
      CGSTAmt,      
      SGST,      
      SGSTAmt,      
      TotValue,      
      ISNULL(BP, 0),      
      ISNULL(Amount, 0),      
      BV,      
      ISNULL(IGSTAmt, 0),      
      CGST,      
      CGSTAmt,      
      SGST,      
      SGSTAmt      
 FROM tmpRPProductsItems t      
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1      
      ProdItemId      
    FROM ProductItemCodes      
    WHERE pid = t.pid) ic      
    WHERE UQID = @UqId      
    AND sessionid = @SessId      
    AND RegId = @RegId      
    AND FId = @FId      
      
  INSERT INTO RepurchasePayments_Reg (Regid, RMid, Mop, MopNo, MopDate, MopBank, Amount, Sesid, DDNo, ChequeNo, vouchercode)      
    SELECT      
      @regid,      
      @RMid,      
      MOP,      
      @MopRefNo,      
      @Billdate,      
      '',      
      Amount,      
      @sessid,      
      DDNo,      
      '',      
      ''      
    FROM TmpPayments      
    WHERE Uniqid = @UqId      
    AND SessId = @SessId      
    AND RegId = @RegId      
    AND FId = @FId      
      
  IF (@ReqToType = 'Stores')      
  BEGIN      
    INSERT INTO RepurchaseReqToAddress_Reg (Rmid, Code, Name, Addr, State, District, City, Pincode, Mobile, Email, GSTNo)      
      SELECT      
        @RMid,      
        'Stores',      
        Name,      
        Address,      
        State,      
        District,      
        City,      
        LEFT(Pincode, 6),      
        LEFT(Mobile, 15),      
        Email,      
        LEFT(GSTNo, 15)      
      FROM StoreProfileAddress(NOLOCK)      
      WHERE CountryId = @CountryId      
      
      
    INSERT INTO RepurchaseAddress_Reg (Rmid, Name, Addr, State, District, City, Mobile, Email, Pincode, GSTNo)      
      SELECT      
        @RMid,      
        @SName,      
        @Addr,      
        @StId,      
        @District,      
        @City,      
        @Mobile,      
        Email,      
        @Pin,      
        LEFT(GSTNo, 15)      
      FROM StoreProfileAddress(NOLOCK)      
      WHERE CountryId = @CountryId
```

Comment: We can't help you until and unless you show us your code and tell us _exactly_ what RDBMS you're using (vendor, name, edition, version). May I ask how else you expected us to help you?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. Can you clarify the exact problem you are facing?

Comment: When product order,I need to insert data into multiple tables .When multiple customers are ordering at the same time(Multiple server hits).some tables are not inserting (or) inserting with different bill no.